# Issue with Express and middleware

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, middleware

```
function redit (req, res, next) {

 var session = req.session.user;

 if (session) {

    res.redirect('/home');

    next();

 }

 else {

    res.redirect('/');

    next();

 }

}

app.get('/', redit, function (req, res){

   res.render('home0.ejs');

});
```

I code this middleware to check if there's a req.session.user, if there is, the user would be redirected to `home`, if not, would be redirected to `/`. But when this middleware is called, Chrome says to me `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)'`, any solutions...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the fact that after redirect an anonymous user (with falsy `req.session.user` value) will end up at the same (`/`) page - so their identity will be checked up by `redir` middleware again... and again... and again. Hence the 'TOO MANY REDIRECTS' error.

The common solution is to redirect all the anonymouses to some other gateway page - and that page obviously should NOT check `session.user`.